# ScalaCheck Arbitrary case class with random data generation (Magnolia)

Tags: scala, scalatest, scalacheck, magnolia-scala

Using a basic example I'm attempting to randomly generate a bunch of Person (`case class Person(name: String, age: Int`) instances using [this library](https://github.com/DanielaSfregola/random-data-generator-magnolia) for random data generation.

The problem I'm running into is when creating an Arbitrary that has bound limits for the age parameter as shown below.

```
  val arbPersonUnder18: Arbitrary[Person] = Arbitrary(
    for {
      name <- Gen.alphaStr
      age <- Gen.chooseNum(Int.MinValue, 17)
    } yield Person(name, age)
  )

  "validatePersonForAlcohol" should {
    "ensure people with age less than 18 cannot buy alcohol" in {
      implicit val _: Arbitrary[Person] = arbPersonUnder18
      forAll { person: Person =>
        ...
      }
    }
  }
```

Which results in `could not find implicit value for parameter arbA: org.scalacheck.Arbitrary[pbtexample.Person]`

I can't see why it's not able to find the arbitrary it needs, any advice would be great.

Comment: @jwvh that's it, thank you :)
If you post this as the answer I will be happy to mark it as accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though an implicit value is seldom, if ever, referenced by name, it still needs one, what the language spec calls a "stable identifier."

Using `_` as the variable name tells the compiler that it can forget about this value after it's been created.